# PLS-00103; is with authid as cluster compress order using compiled wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable pipel

Tags: oracle, plsql

While writing the below pl/sql procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RTSPGMR."COMPARE"
DECLARE CURSOR comp IS
select EFF_DT,LOC_EFF_DT_FK from dcp d,loc l where D.LOC_CD_FK=L.LOC_CD;

BEGIN

for c1 in comp LOOP

if EFF_DT=LOC_EFF_DT_FK THEN

dbms_output.put_line('dates are equal');

Else
dbms_output.put_line('dates are not equal');

end if;

   END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

I am getting the following error.

> [Error] PLS-00103 (5: 1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE"
>   when expecting one of the following:    ( ; is with authid as cluster
>   compress order using compiled    wrapped external deterministic
>   parallel_enable pipel

Comment: Which database are you actually using?  MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming rest of your code is fine, the syntax for procedure is incorrect. You don't need a `declare` and also you are missing `as` or `is` after procedure name. Try this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RTSPGMR.COMPARE is
CURSOR comp IS
select EFF_DT,LOC_EFF_DT_FK from dcp d,loc l where D.LOC_CD_FK=L.LOC_CD;
BEGIN
    for c1 in comp LOOP
        if EFF_DT=LOC_EFF_DT_FK THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('dates are equal');
        else
            dbms_output.put_line('dates are not equal');
        end if;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```